# Encrypting image files in python3 using RSA algo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, rsa, public-key-encryption

i am encrypting images in python3 by using RSA algo, but i am getting some error when i run the code;
the error is:

```
 File "encrypt_blob.py", line 59, in <module>
 encrypted_blob = encrypt_blob(unencrypted_blob, public_key)
 File "encrypt_blob.py", line 37, in encrypt_blob
 chunk += " " * (chunk_size - len(chunk))
 TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

I have generated the keys previously and using those in this script to encrypt the image file. But i am getting this error. as i have found this code on a blog, I think the code is written on python2 but i am using python3, and i don't know how to resolve the problem

The code is:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import zlib
import base64

def encrypt_blob(blob, public_key):
  #Import the Public Key and use for encryption using PKCS1_OAEP
  rsa_key = RSA.importKey(public_key)
  rsa_key = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsa_key)

  #compress the data first
  blob = zlib.compress(blob)

  #In determining the chunk size, determine the private key length used in bytes
#and subtract 42 bytes (when using PKCS1_OAEP). The data will be in encrypted
#in chunks
chunk_size = 470
print(type(chunk_size))
offset = 0
end_loop = False
encrypted =  ""
print(type(encrypted))

while not end_loop:
    #The chunk
    chunk = (blob[offset:offset + chunk_size])

    #If the data chunk is less then the chunk size, then we need to add
    #padding with " ". This indicates the we reached the end of the file
    #so we end loop here
    if len(chunk) % chunk_size != 0:
        end_loop = True
        chunk += " " * (chunk_size - len(chunk))

    #Append the encrypted chunk to the overall encrypted file
    encrypted += (rsa_key.encrypt(chunk))

    #Increase the offset by chunk size
    offset += chunk_size

#Base 64 encode the encrypted file
return base64.b64encode(encrypted)

#Use the public key for encryption
fd = open("public_key.pem", "rb")
public_key = fd.read()
fd.close()

#Our candidate file to be encrypted
fd = open("img.jpg", "rb")
unencrypted_blob = fd.read()
fd.close()

encrypted_blob = encrypt_blob(unencrypted_blob, public_key)

#Write the encrypted contents to a file
fd = open("encrypted_img.jpg", "wb")
fd.write(encrypted_blob)
fd.close()
```

Looking forward to suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**some typecasting error is there & encoding was not mentioned**

---

Comment used: `#Append the encrypted chunk to the overall encrypted file`

WRONG:
`encrypted += (rsa_key.encrypt(chunk))`

RIGHT:
`encrypted += str(rsa_key.encrypt(chunk))`

---

Comment used: `#Base 64 encode the encrypted file`

WRONG:
`return base64.b64encode(encrypted)`

RIGHT:
`return base64.b64encode(encrypted.encode('ascii'))`

---

ENTIRE CODE:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import zlib
import base64
def encrypt_blob(blob, public_key):
    rsa_key = RSA.importKey(public_key)
    rsa_key = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsa_key)
    blob = zlib.compress(blob)
    chunk_size = 470
    offset = 0
    end_loop = False
    encrypted =  ""
    while not end_loop:    
        chunk = blob[offset:offset + chunk_size]
        if len(chunk) % chunk_size != 0:
            end_loop = True
            chunk += bytes(" " * (chunk_size - len(chunk)),'utf-8')
        encrypted += str(rsa_key.encrypt(chunk))
        offset += chunk_size
    #print(type(encrypted))
    return base64.b64encode(encrypted.encode('ascii'))

fd = open("public_key.pem", "rb")
public_key = fd.read()
fd.close()

fd = open("img.jpg", "rb")
unencrypted_blob = fd.read()
fd.close()

encrypted_blob = encrypt_blob(unencrypted_blob, public_key)
fd = open("encrypted_img.jpg", "wb")
fd.write(encrypted_blob)
fd.close()
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The original code is written for Python2.
In Python3, you cannot convert bytes object to str implicitly.
So basically to solve that error about "concatenate str (not "bytes") to str", you must declare the variables as a byte string.

1. encrypted = b""
2. chunk += b" " * (chunk_size - len(chunk))

Hope that helps.